# Can I use sed to insert a pattern into a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, json

I want to generate a file that starts in the format:

```
# topics-to-move.json
{
    "topics": [],
    "version": 1
}
```

with no `{ "topic": "<topic_name>" }` entries in `"topics":[]`. I can grab the topic names from another script, which would give me a clean list of:

```
Topic..A
Topic..B
Topic..C
```

I'd like to be able to insert each of the above into a file `topics-to-move.json`, in the format of `{"topic":"Topic..A"},{"topic":"Topic..B"},{"topic":"Topic..C"}` -- can this be achieved using `sed` or something similar?

For clarity, the final file should look like:

```
# topics-to-move.json
{
    "topics": [
        {"topic":"Topic..A"},
        {"topic":"Topic..B"},
        {"topic":"Topic..C"}
    ],
    "version": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a series of sed commands with some cheats:

to replace the first line and mark a starting point, do an in line replace

```
sed -i 's/"topics": \[\],/"topics": \[/g' file.out
```

then re-add the ending of that original line and format with four prepended spaces

```
sed -i '/"topics": \[/a\ \ \ \ \],' file.out
```

then build an array from your other file

```
IFS=$'\n'
topic=( $(sed -n '/^Topic/p' file.in) )
unset IFS
```

then in reverse order from the array, fill the spaces in between the first two seds

```
for (( i=${#topic[@]}-1 ; i>=0 ; i-- )); do sed -E -i '/"topics": \[/a\ \ \ \ {"topic":"'"${topic[$i]}"'},' file.out; done
```

the output is exact (save for a single comma):

```
# topics-to-move.json
{
    "topics": [
        {"topic":"Topic..A"},
        {"topic":"Topic..B"},
        {"topic":"Topic..C"},
    ],
    "version": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way is using json processors like **jq**:

Assuming `topic_names` file:

```
TopicA
TopicB
TopicC
```

---

```
jq --slurpfile topics <(sed 's/^\|$/"/g' topic_names) \
 '.topics = ($topics | map({"topic":.}))' topics-to-move.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "topics": [
    {
      "topic": "TopicA"
    },
    {
      "topic": "TopicB"
    },
    {
      "topic": "TopicC"
    }
  ],
  "version": 1
}
```